# Advanced Search in Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, jquery, autodesk-forge

I have a custom extension in Autodesk Forge.

[image]

The extension lists the elements of the model in the `first Drop-Down`. It lists the properties associated with the selected element in the `second Drop-Down` and in the `third Drop-Down` it gives the values associated with the selected property. When a value is selected in the `third Drop-Down` the `viewer` has to zoom to that specific element. The code that I'm using right now is something like this

```js
$('#' + item.value).change(function() {
  var selection = this.value;
  var itemvalue = $('#' + item.value).find('option:selected').text();
  var searchStr = itemvalue;
  var searchfor = $('#' + item.prop).find('option:selected').text();
  var searchPropList = new Array(searchfor);
  viewer.search(searchStr, searchCallback, searchErrorCallback, searchPropList);
});

function searchCallback(ids) {
  alert(ids);
  _viewer.isolate(ids);
  _viewer.fitToView(ids);
}

function searchErrorCallback(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

};
```

But, It is taking only the values of first second and the third Drop-Downs and I need to include the value of first Drop-Down as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question correctly... the search function is rather limited, it will return a list of dbIds with a property value that matches the search criteria, there is no way to modify its behavior, but since you selected a specific component and know its dbId in the first dropdown, you could simply filter the list return by search to keep only the ids matching with the first ...

Comment: Ok, Got it. Thank you @PhilippeLeefsma